# Sealing threaded PVC pipe

Tags: pvc

What is recommended for Connecting 1" Schedule 80 PVC threaded fittings to prevent leaks. I have tried pipe dope, but leaks developed between nipples and elbows. Do you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

We use liquid sealant all the time with great success at 1-1/2" diameter and less.

- Make sure you are coating the threads completely and evenly.
- Some dopes require coating both male and female ends over certain sizes.
- Maybe try a different brand.
- Might just use teflon tape instead.
- Plumber we know for a large local company uses teflon (to seal) and
  pipe dope (to lubricate) at the same time although we do not practice
  the same.
- If these don't work, look at your threads and make sure they do not
  have a scratch or nick in them.

Comment: I've had the best success so far with "PTFE pipe dope" (which is to say, try a different brand and or type, yes.)